# Dropbox Installation in single folder Windows XP & Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, dropbox

I have dual boot OS, Windows XP and Windows 7. I have already installed Dropbox in Windows XP. I have installed the Dropbox client in Windows 7 but when I tried moving the folder location to it, in XP it says 'Target Folder contains Dropbox'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should give you an option to merge.
2. Just to make sure, you might be setting Dropbox folder one level up. Make sure you're using the correct path.