# OneDrive in same folder for both Windows 7 and Windows 10 on same PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, onedrive

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/707113/), but with OneDrive, and with Win7 & Win10.

I have my PC set up with dual boot to Windows 7 and Windows 10 -- they are two separate partitions on the same SSD. Now, I want to use OneDrive from both OS's, but I want its physical disk location to be on a **separate** drive that's NOT the OS SSD. So let's say the OS partitions are `C:` & `D:`, respectively depending on which is running of course. I have a dedicated 'data' drive, call it drive `H:`; thus I want OneDrive to use `H:\OneDrive`. **From both OS's**.

It **seems** that MS makes this nearly impossible. In each OS's case, when the OneDrive app "takes control over" that folder, it **breaks** the *other* OS's hold on the folder, rendering it inoperable to said other OS.

Hope there is a way! Thank you folks. For context, assume I'm a fairly competent power-user and understand basic NTFS permissions, and am moderately comfortable with CMD & PowerShell when given direction.

PS: I also read [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/1308909/), but I'm not sure if I follow it 100%, especially because of the conflicting answers. I know *about* symlinks and junctions, at a super basic level (like, I can create them and see that they work), so if that's part of the answer, great. But again, just not super sure if this is all possible & worthwhile, or a completely futile effort.

Comment: There are third-party tools that will allow you to mount your OneDrive account and make it act as a network drive.  I would try one of those applications if that would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reply. Any specific suggestions?